# LiveCycle / JBoss JNDI error : Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, rmi, livecycle

I have Adobe LiveCycle ES4 Server running on an older version of JBoss on a Windows 7 machine. On another Windows machine within the same network, I set up a client also running on JBoss, but a newer version (7.1.1). Using sample code provided by Adobe, I am trying to test my connection over RMI, but I am running into errors. Here is the stack trace:

```
09:53:18,369 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000230: Schema export complete
09:53:18,370 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment jboss-as-kitchensink-jsp.war
09:53:18,438 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /jboss-as-kitchensink-jsp
09:53:18,528 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "jboss-as-kitchensink-jsp.war" with deployment "jboss-as-kitchensink-jsp.war"
09:53:26,035 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) ALC-DSC-031-000: com.adobe.idp.dsc.net.DSCNamingException: Remote EJBObject lookup failed for ejb/Invocation provider
09:53:26,036 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.ejb.EjbMessageDispatcher.initialise(EjbMessageDispatcher.java:101)
09:53:26,037 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.ejb.EjbMessageDispatcher.doSend(EjbMessageDispatcher.java:141)
09:53:26,037 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.base.AbstractMessageDispatcher.send(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:69)
09:53:26,038 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at com.adobe.idp.dsc.clientsdk.ServiceClient.invoke(ServiceClient.java:208)
09:53:26,038 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at com.adobe.livecycle.readerextensions.client.ReaderExtensionsServiceClient.invoke(ReaderExtensionsServiceClient.java:58)
09:53:26,039 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at com.adobe.livecycle.readerextensions.client.ReaderExtensionsServiceClient.applyUsageRights(ReaderExtensionsServiceClient.java:105)
09:53:26,040 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.quickstarts.kitchensinkjsp.servlet.AdobeServlet.applyUsageRights(AdobeServlet.java:118)
09:53:26,040 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.quickstarts.kitchensinkjsp.servlet.AdobeServlet.doPost(AdobeServlet.java:75)
09:53:26,041 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
09:53:26,041 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
09:53:26,042 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
09:53:26,043 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
09:53:26,043 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
09:53:26,044 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
09:53:26,044 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
09:53:26,045 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
09:53:26,046 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
09:53:26,046 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
09:53:26,047 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
09:53:26,047 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
09:53:26,048 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
09:53:26,048 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
09:53:26,049 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
09:53:26,049 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
09:53:26,050 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
09:53:26,051 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
09:53:26,051 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
09:53:26,052 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.jboss-as-kitchensink-jsp.war:main" from Service Module Loader
09:53:26,053 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(InitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:64)
09:53:26,053 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
09:53:26,054 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
09:53:26,054 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
09:53:26,055 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
09:53:26,055 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.ejb.EjbMessageDispatcher.initJndiContext(EjbMessageDispatcher.java:228)
09:53:26,056 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.ejb.EjbMessageDispatcher.getJndiContext(EjbMessageDispatcher.java:241)
09:53:26,057 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.ejb.EjbMessageDispatcher.initialise(EjbMessageDispatcher.java:91)
09:53:26,057 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   ... 26 more
```

Here is my code:

```
protected void applyUsageRights() {

try {

    //Set connection properties required to invoke LiveCycle                                 
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties(); 
    connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_DEFAULT_EJB_ENDPOINT, "jnp://113.252.20.43:1099"); 
    connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL,ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_EJB_PROTOCOL);           
    connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_SERVER_TYPE, "JBoss"); 
    connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_CREDENTIAL_USERNAME, MY_USER); 
    connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_CREDENTIAL_PASSWORD, MY_PASSWORD); 

    //Create a ServiceClientFactory object 
    ServiceClientFactory myFactory = ServiceClientFactory.createInstance(connectionProps); 

    //Create a ReaderExtensionsServiceClient object 
    ReaderExtensionsServiceClient reClient = new ReaderExtensionsServiceClient(myFactory);  

    //Retrieve the PDF document to which to apply usage rights 
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\sample.pdf");  
    Document inputPDF = new Document(fileInputStream); 

    //Create a UsageRight object and specify specific usage rights 
    UsageRights useRight = new UsageRights();  
    useRight.setEnabledDynamicFormFields(true); 
    useRight.setEnabledComments(true); 
    useRight.setEnabledFormFillIn(true); 
    useRight.setEnabledDigitalSignatures(true); 

    //Create a ReaderExtensionsOptions object 
    ReaderExtensionsOptionSpec reOptions = new ReaderExtensionsOptionSpec();  

    //Set the usage rights  
    reOptions.setUsageRights(useRight);  
    reOptions.setMessage("This is a Rights-Enabled PDF Document"); 

    //Apply usage rights to a PDF document 
    Document rightsEnabledPDF = reClient.applyUsageRights( 
       inputPDF, 
       "RE2", 
      null, 
      reOptions);  

    //Create a new PDF file that represents the rights-enabled PDF document 
    File resultFile = new File("C:\\Adobe\\LoanUsageRights.pdf");  
    rightsEnabledPDF.copyToFile(resultFile); 

  }catch (Exception e) { 
       e.printStackTrace(); 
  }         
}
```

Comment: please post the rest of the stacktrace.

Comment: I've edited my post to include the rest of the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work using SOAP?

```
connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_DEFAULT_SOAP_ENDPOINT, "http://113.252.20.43:80"); 
connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL,ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_SOAP_PROTOCOL);
```

I personally have not had success calling an EJB endpoint on a remote LiveCycle server.  Would like to see your solution if you get it worked out.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is ni problem just include jboss-client classes to to your classpath. In jboss 5 vs jboss 4x there are plenty of them. But IT works. My configuration LC es4 on Linux and jboss 5.2, calling remote from jboss 6 with the client classes from jboss 5 using the Java api